# Copy DIV content to another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i copy the contents of DIV1 to DIV2 on load of the page using jquery? I've tried

```
$('.buffer').html($("#beskeder_vis").html());
```

However i wasn't able to make it work out

Comment: Remember: `$('.buffer')` may select multiple elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your selectors are correct, you should put your code in the .ready() Event.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

So something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.buffer').html(jQuery("#beskeder_vis").html());
}
```

Otherwise jQuery won't be able to find your elements, since the DOM isn't loaded, when your function is executed.

Answer (score 3):

You should bind event handler on ready event. See documentation: [ready funciton](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.buffer').html($("#beskeder_vis").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#two').html($('#one').html());
```

See this [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/UKBxH/)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. It may have something to do with the jquery version your using
Proof [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weightlossexp/5G439/)