# Getting the contents of div to another div along with the input fields data

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I need the contents of `div1` to be copied to another `div2`.

The contents of the `div1` contains a fileupload control(HTML5), generated on the fly using javascript.

I've tried like this using `jQuery`.

```
$('#div2').html($('#div1').html());
```

With the above code it only shows the `html` but the path of file in the fileupload control is missing.

I even tried using `javascript` this:

```
var va = document.getElementById('div1');
document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML=va.innerHTML
```

But that doesn't help though. It resulted in the same, fileupload control is being displayed but without the filepath in it.

I've tried replacing the `innerHTML` with `innerText` but it shows the html content as text.

I've tried with `appendTo` in `jQuery`, it works but it copies entire `div1` to `div2`. I only need the contents to be copied but not the entire  div.

I've checked

[Copy div content to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743538/copy-div-content-to-another-div)

That doesnt help though.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVjzA/1/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `fileupload` control does not have its contents copied as a user (client) security measure. There is nothing you can do about it.

You can however *move* the *actual* elements around (not copy them) as demonstrated in the modified fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AVjzA/3/).

I have not tested this cross-browser and I would still recommend against trying anything fancy with the fileupload control as there is no saying when browsers will lock it down even more.

**EDIT :** I am adding a reference link as @nbrooks suggested in the comments.

If you have time for some reading: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/61326.html

Comment: +1 good answer. Do you have a source discussing the security measures preventing copying with the path?

Comment: @nbrooks I'd have to search for a source but in general am I required to quote a source in the answer (other than that it's a well known fact among hardened web programmers)?

Comment: Not required, but it's usually helpful...especially for people who are genuinely curious (like me) or skeptical.

Comment: @nbrooks I've added a link but you may want to note here that any article about this issue will only highlight why the file input does not accept values from the programmers. Any file input manipulation by the programmer (including cloning) will mostly trigger the browser to kick in its security measures.

Answer (score 1):

Plz Checkout this Code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
          $in=$(this);
          $("#div2").append ( $in.val() );
    });
});​
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/AVjzA/5/)

Comment: sorry my bad. plz check now .

Comment: +1 Thanks for you code. I need to get it along with the upload control. But your code shows only path to the uploaded file. Can you please modify you code. I'm new to jquery and jscript

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datasubmit').click(function(){
             //var data = $('#div1')[0].innerHTML;

            //$('#div2')[0].innerHTML += data;
            $("#div2").append($("#div1").clone());
        });
    });
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AVjzA/2/

Comment: `clone` doesn't copy the file path.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It doesnt work though. I think you are using firefox.It doesnt work in chrome and ie

Comment: @Karthik.. I am using FF its working there..will check for ie